# How to add click handlers to every element which has a certain class?

Tags: jquery

I want to add on each element which has the class .ui-icon-trash a click handler which needs to provide a datatable object (this I have already) and the row which should be deleted. I do not know how to iterate over my elements to add the clickhandler and also I dont know how to retrieve the current tr for each iteration.

```
 $(".ui-icon-trash").click(function(){
        deleteRowFromTable(oTable, ????The TR of the current element????);          

    });
```

here is my table

```
        <table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <th>Property</th>
            <th>Value</th>      
            <th></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <button id="create-property">Create new property</button>

            <tr >
                <td>mailAddress_object</td>
                <td id="mailAddress_object" >Message from SendALL 2.5</td>      
                <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="deleteRow_1" name="mailAddress_object"></span></td>                     
            </tr>       

            <tr >
                <td>mjmj</td>
                <td id="mjmj" >xcvxcv</td>      
                <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="deleteRow_2" name="mjmj"></span></td>                       
            </tr>       

            <tr >
                <td>olol</td>
                <td id="olol" >kjkkjk</td>      
                <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="deleteRow_3" name="olol"></span></td>                       
            </tr>       

            <tr >
                <td>plsUrl</td>
                <td id="plsUrl" >http://komm2.srs-management.de</td>        
                <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="deleteRow_4" name="plsUrl"></span></td>                     
            </tr>       

            <tr >
                <td>scPwd</td>
                <td id="scPwd" >sysadm</td>     
                <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="deleteRow_5" name="scPwd"></span></td>                      
            </tr>       

            <tr >
                <td>smtp</td>
                <td id="smtp" >YOUR_MAILSERVER</td>     
                <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="deleteRow_6" name="smtp"></span></td>                       
            </tr>       

            <tr >
                <td>test</td>
                <td id="test" >test3</td>       
                <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="deleteRow_7" name="test"></span></td>                       
            </tr>       

            <tr >
                <td>useEncryption</td>
                <td id="useEncryption" >false</td>      
                <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="deleteRow_8" name="useEncryption"></span></td>                      
            </tr>       

        </tbody>    
        </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("body").on('click', ".ui-icon-trash" ,function(){

    var $closestTr = $(this).closest('tr');  // This will give the closest tr
                            // If the class element is the child of tr          

     $closestTr.remove() ;  // Will delete that
 });
```

You need to add some text inside the span , otherwise you cannot see the span..
I just added the delete text to the span `with class .ui-icon-trash`

[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/49TFL/)